# How can I keep a fixed element contained inside a relative element?

Tags: jquery, css, html, css-position

I have a fixed element (div) that I want to scroll with my page. However, when the fixed element reaches the end of the container (div) I want it to stop scrolling with the page.

I'm trying to do this with CSS, or is jquery my best option?

Comment: You'll need to use JavaScript. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216114/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907367/

Comment: This sounds like jQuery, since fixed cannot do this.

Answer (score 0):

Elements with `position:fixed` are positioned relative to the body, not the containing element. You probably won't be able to do this without using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an event with `$(window).scroll()` and compare the position of the div container and the fixed element.

When they are equal switch the position style from `fixed` to `absolute` and set left and top accordingly. When the user scolls back, do the opposite.