# Scrollto while scrolling

Tags: javascript

I isolated the most I can my code into this : http://jsfiddle.net/uXVWu/

HTML :

```
<a id="stopHere" >Hi !</a>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
```

JS :

```
var theAnchor=document.getElementById("stopHere");
var tempX,tempY;

function stopScroll(e)
{
    var c=parseInt(document.getElementById('stopHere').offsetWidth);
    var d=parseInt(document.getElementById('stopHere').offsetHeight);
    if(tempX<=c&&tempY<=300+d&&0<=tempX&&300<=tempY)window.scrollTo(0,200);
}

function update(e)
{
    var doc=document.documentElement;
    var body=document.body;
    tempX=(e.pageX)?e.pageX:e.clientX+(doc&&doc.scrollLeft||body&&body.scrollLeft||0)-(doc&&doc.clientLeft||body&&body.clientLeft||0);
    tempY=(e.pageY)?e.pageY:e.clientY+(doc&&doc.scrollTop||body&&body.scrollTop||0)-(doc&&doc.clientTop||body&&body.clientTop||0);
}

window.onscroll=stopScroll;
window.onmousemove=update;
```

CSS :

```
#stopHere
{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
}
```

What does the program is that if the cursor is on the `<a>`, then you scroll, the `<a>` will be on the top. What I want is that you scroll over it and it goes on the top. How can it works?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907367/have-a-div-cling-to-top-of-screen-if-scrolled-down-past-it

Comment: Can you please repeat the desired result, perhaps with a few more words - I have trouble understanding what you want to achive, so I can't help at the moment...

Comment: It means that you keep scrolling and at the same time the cursor pass over the anchor.

Comment: Do you want to pin the <a /> box at the top of the window while the rest of the page still stays scrollable?

Comment: No. To scroll to the `a` position.

Comment: Do you mean something in the means of this? http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/ Just animated?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/GTSaz/1/

So that if, when you are scrolling, your mouse is over the  element the scrolling will jump down to have the element at the top of the viewport (0,300 in this case).

Also, if you don't want to hardcode the position (0,300) then you can detect in in the script, see http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html

Comment: You understood what I want! But even in your exemple, when you 'scroll over' the `a` a little bit fast, it doesn't catch it.

Comment: Then detect the position (http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html) and the size (`offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight`) of the <a> element, and check if the mouse is either in that area, or nearby (pick your desired threshold), and then make it scroll

Comment: But it's what I did in the exemple in my question !!! I just replaced the calculations of top left by 0 and 300 (cause it's absolute positionning here) **BUT** try the exemple and see ! you must put the mouse over the `a` then start scrolling!!!

Comment: I identified the problem since I asked the main question : while you scroll, the tempX and tempY aren't updated !!!!!

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding correctly, you could set it up at top of the page simpler using something like:

```
document.getElementById('stopHere').style.position="fixed"
document.getElementById('stopHere').style.top="0"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what do you want . Do you want a `fixed` div or `window.scroll(0,0)`

But, I have combined your's and Adam's code, to workaround the situation.

http://jsfiddle.net/c3CJF/1/

**Markup:**

```
<a id="stopHere" >Hi !</a>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
```

**CSS:**

```
#stopHere
{
    position:absolute;
    top:300px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
var theAnchor=document.getElementById("stopHere");
var tempX,tempY;
var docBody = document.body,
    docEl = document.documentElement,
    scrollElement = /WebKit/.test(navigator.userAgent) || document.compatMode == 'BackCompat' ? docBody : docEl;
var lastScrollTop = scrollElement.scrollTop;
function stopScroll(e)
{
    // Extra check to make if your scroll passes the element on its movement
    if((scrollElement.scrollTop - lastScrollTop + tempY) >= 300){
       window.scrollTo(0,300);
    }
    lastScrollTop = scrollElement.scrollTop;
    var c=parseInt(document.getElementById('stopHere').offsetWidth);
    var d=parseInt(document.getElementById('stopHere').offsetHeight);
    /* the if is to test if the mouse is over the anchor */
    if(tempX<=c&&tempY<=300+d&&0<=tempX&&300<=tempY)window.scrollTo(0,300);
}

function update(e)//to have the x and y of the mouse
{
    var doc=document.documentElement;
    var body=document.body;
    tempX=(e.pageX)?e.pageX:e.clientX+(doc&&doc.scrollLeft||body&&body.scrollLeft||0)-(doc&&doc.clientLeft||body&&body.clientLeft||0);
    tempY=(e.pageY)?e.pageY:e.clientY+(doc&&doc.scrollTop||body&&body.scrollTop||0)-(doc&&doc.clientTop||body&&body.clientTop||0);

}

window.onscroll=stopScroll;
window.onmousemove=update;
```