# Using JavaScript/JQuery to display text only on scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to create a page that contains hidden text that is only revealed when someone scrolls.

As someone scrolls past a `div`, that text should disappear, while the new text is revealed.

I only was able to find solutions for scroll vertically or horizontally, etc.

I have created a [**simpler version**](http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepj/x8tzg/21/) of this using jsFiddle, but not matter what code I add to the JS part, nothing seems to work.

**Here is the css:**

```
body {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    margin: 5px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

div#mainText {
    width: 960px;
    margin: o auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    font-size: 1em;
}

h1 {
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color: gray;
}

h2 {
    font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:2.5em;
}

.partOne
{
    color: gray;
    display:none;
}

.partTwo
{
    color: gray;
    display:none;
}

.partThree
{
    color: gray;
    display:none;
}

.kicker
{
    color: gray;
    display:none;
}
```

**Here is the HTML:**

```
<h1 id="preHead">Catchy Title</h1>
<h2 id="headline">Headline goes here</h2>
<P></p>
<p id="introBlurb">A very compelling blurb here. Praesent volutpat rhoncus purus,         ullamcorper dapibus ante pulvinar non. Maecenas fringilla justo nec justo blandit non rhoncus nunc elementum.</p>

<div class="partOne">
    <p>Part one here. This appears on first scroll event.</p>
</div>

<div class="partTwo">
    <p>Part two here. This appears on second scroll event.</p>
</div>   

<div class="kicker">
    <p>Kicker here. This appears on 3rd scroll event.</p>
</div>​
```

**JavaScript/Jquery:**

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
    $("kicker").css("display"); 
});
```

Nothing's worked so far. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what you mean by "1st,2nd,3rd scroll events" ? scroll generate several tens of events per second when you scrolling

Comment: also your sample is to short to be scrolled

Comment: Not to mention you're selecting on an element, not a class. use `$(".kicker")`

Comment: you're right. my actual page has a lot more text at each div so there would be scrolling involved. what i meant by first scroll is  that i want each part to be revealed as people get toward the bottom of each div, perhaps with some sort of anchor.

Comment: thanks...and i have tried $(".kicker") but didn't seem to work either. i will try again.

Comment: i just updated the jsfiddle with more text and $(".kicker"). thx

Comment: The `.css('display')` is simply a getter for the css property.  It won't have any effect.  Check my answer for a working example at  http://jsfiddle.net/x8tzg/24/

Answer (score 1):

Your example wasn't long enough to scroll, so I added some extra text in the first element.  The main issue was with your jQuery.  You were calling `$('kicker').css('display')` which didn't work.

The selector `'kicker'` needed to be changed to `'.kicker'` because it was a class, and I changed `.css('display')` to be `.show()` which worked correctly.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/x8tzg/24/

Note:  If you want to detect when a certain scroll point is reached, you can add code in the `scroll` event to check the `$(window).scrollTop()` compared to `$(compareElement).offset().top` as mentioned here: [Have a div cling to top of screen if scrolled down past it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907367/have-a-div-cling-to-top-of-screen-if-scrolled-down-past-it).

Comment: Thank you. that worked in the jsfiddle site. much appreciated.