# Fixed DIV disables drop-down-menu

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, fixed

I'm quite new to the world of webdesign and are learning alot from trying different things.

So I'm trying to implement the idea of this [Dock-When-Scroll solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907367/have-a-div-cling-to-top-of-screen-if-scrolled-down-past-it/2907906#2907906?newreg=ecc9d49decf3440494ef1d2b4076d49f) and the basics works pretty well.

Then I added a html/CSS dropdownmenu (with few relative sub-links) within the absolute/fixed DIV and suddenly I can't click or hover the main buttons anymore. I've tried with different z-index values and combinations, adding absolute & relative positions to the menu itself And to make the menu itself the absolute/fixed element but i'm failing.

I've looked around for answers and scratched my head enough, I'm sure I'm overlooking something, the DIV is covering the menu somehow. Is there a rule with fixed elements that I'm missing?

Any help appreciated

*Update 2*

So after redoing the position-homework and tested various properties of this premade menu I've noticed there's a bugg with the hover. Is this possible?

*Update 3*

Okay I think I'll need some sleep, but basically the menu works in the default Static position and stops to work when "fixed" is turned on.

*UPDATED SOLVED*

Okay thanks for those who thought about the issue!

I succeded to figure out the problem alot easier with the jsfiddler so credit goes to Caramba :)

The code lied with my editing of adamJlev's solution of the clinging menu.

The problem-script:

```
             var $window = $(window),
           $stickyEl = $('#cssmenu'),
           $stickyEl2 = $('#bannerloggo'),

           elTop = $stickyEl.offset().top;
           elTop = $stickyEl2.offset().top;

           $window.scroll(function() {
            $stickyEl.toggleClass('sticky', $window.scrollTop() > elTop);
            $stickyEl2.toggleClass('sticky2', $window.scrollTop() > elTop);
        });
```

The fix:

```
             var $window = $(window),
           $stickyEl = $('#cssmenu'),

           elTop = $stickyEl.offset().top;

           $window.scroll(function() {
            $stickyEl.toggleClass('sticky', $window.scrollTop() > elTop);
        });
```

That easy.. So I'll read some more about Javascript.

Cheers

Comment: please add the code you have so far or even better create a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/ and you will get answers!

Comment: Oh yes, ofcourse! Here's the jsfiddle, great tool by the way! I'm trying to troubleshoot the code myself atm, (http://jsfiddle.net/PMmm6/](fiddle) this fiddle is the menu-core. It doesn't cling in the fiddle for some reason but works in its context, the menu just becomes inusable after the actual clinging.

Answer (score 1):

So I'm a newbie with this Stackoverflow-system, bear with me. I updated the question with explanation of the issue and the simple solution.