# Form to stick and then scroll with page (when hitting the top) to a certain point then scroll again

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I am currently trying to get a form to start scrolling with results on a page to a certain point and then move along with it. If that makes sense.

Example here: http://77pixels.com/clients/sos/results-page/index_scroll.html > Works in Firefox, Chrome & Safari it is messy.

It needs to scroll up until it hits the top then be set at position: fixed but once the bottom of the form hits parallel to the bottom of the last result then it sticks there and moves up with the page.

I'm not 100% sure if this is even possible.

Any help on this would be superb. Many many thanks.

- Suleiman

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the kind of thing that happens on [the lesscss.org page](http://lesscss.org) then, check this already existing answer: [How can I make a div stick to the top of the screen once it's been scrolled to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216114/how-can-i-make-a-div-stick-to-the-top-of-the-screen-once-its-been-scrolled-to/2153775#2153775)