# Move Box/Div up or down when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I scroll up or down, I want a box/div to move up or down too.

For example:

See categories box

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can I make a div stick to the top of the screen once it's been scrolled to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216114/how-can-i-make-a-div-stick-to-the-top-of-the-screen-once-its-been-scrolled-to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your css write 
`#my-box { 
  position: fixed; 
}`

it will probably move it from the center so you will have to do some math if it is a fixed width and height box like

```
   #my-box-fixed { 
                     position: fixed; 
                     width:200px; 
                     height: 150px; 
                     top: 50%; 
                     left: 50%; 
                     margin-left: -100px; // half of the width
                     margin-top: -75px; // half of the height
    }
```

Comment: Fixed position can be used only if you have a div that will stay in place (ie - Fixed to the top of the window, left side, etc.). In the example case, they are using javascript to trigger the adjustment when the window reaches a certain point. See link below...

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need: http://blog.yjl.im/2010/01/stick-div-at-top-after-scrolling.html

Answer (score 1):

Also, in javascript you can do:

```
document.getElementById("my-box-fixed").style.position = "fixed";
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do it whit jquery:

```
$().ready(function () {
        var $scrollingDiv = $("#YouDivID");

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            $scrollingDiv
            .stop()
            .animate({ "marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 5) + "px" }, "1000");
        });
    });
```