# make div stick to the top of the screen and stop before hitting the footer

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I'm trying to make a div stick to the header once the user has started scrolling down the page .
I found the example 
[How can I make a div stick to the top of the screen once it's been scrolled to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216114/how-can-i-make-a-div-stick-to-the-top-of-the-screen-once-its-been-scrolled-to)

I used the code that has 24 votes . [Live demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/zsJAr/show/light/).

PROBLEMS : 
 1. I want to make the div stop before hitting the footer. i don't want to show it over the footer .
 2. I don't know why this works with jquery 1.3.2 but not with 1.5.2 or a later version .

ofcourse any other jquery code / plugin or ideea would be great!

Comment: the offset() function changed. You could just remove the {scroll:false} and I think it will work in JQ 1.5.

Comment: Thanks Gerben ! that worked ! removing {scrool:false} made it work with JQ 1.5.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(window).load($(function()
{
    var elem = $("#scroller");
    var top = elem.offset().top;
    var maxTop = $("#footer").offset().top - elem.height();
    var scrollHandler = function()
    {
      var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (scrollTop<top) {
        elem.css({position:"relative",top:""})//should be "static" I think
      } else if (scrollTop>maxTop) {
        elem.css({position:"absolute",top:(maxTop+"px")})
      } else {
        elem.css({position:"fixed",top:"0px"})
      }
    }
    $(window).scroll(scrollHandler);scrollHandler()

}));
```

fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/3ATzd/2/show/
Only think is it doesn't like the margin-top on #scroller. I also removed the need for the scroller-anchor element, so you can remove this.

Comment: great job ! .. but you are right .. it does not like margin-top . and if we set a height of 600px to the scroller we would see that it will go over the footer .. but only 10px or so .
http://fiddle.jshell.net/3ATzd/5/show/

Comment: A dirty trick would be this :
var maxTop = $("#footer").offset().top - elem.height() - 10;

Comment: also I found this : 
http://kitchen.net-perspective.com/open-source/scroll-follow/

But please feel free to share any other info and thanks a lot !

Comment: You could just use padding-top. Or top:"0px" to top:"10px", and maxTop=... to maxTop=...-10