# Div start scrolling when the header reaches its top and stop from scrolling when the its bottom reaches the footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a page called project, in that page there are two grids, one called "imagesGrid" and the other one called "detailsBox", they are floating next to each other using (i.e. both has a width like 50% and display inline-block). I am trying to make the "detailsBox" to start scrolling with the page when the header reaches its top, and stop from scrolling when its bottom reaches the top of the footer. I am also trying to stop the function completely from working and set the "detailsBox" to be positioned as relative when the screen size is below 700px.

I have tried and experimented dozens of tutorials, like: 
[make div stick to the top of the screen and stop before hitting the footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819842/make-div-stick-to-the-top-of-the-screen-and-stop-before-hitting-the-footer) and http://jsfiddle.net/FDv2J/3/ with no hope.

What is the best path to take to solve my problem? Here is a link to a live preview of the page: http://www.loaidesign.co.uk/portfolio ?project=Test_Project
And here is the HTML and the CSS, I don't have a working JavaScript script, and I tired the ones provided in the links above as well as many others from here, google  and codepen, but can't seem to be able to make them work for me.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapperB">
    <div id="portfolio-projectPage" class="content">
        <div class="imagesGrid">
            <p>Website</p>
            <img alt="Adonis Cars Rental website design" src="images/adonis-cars-website.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="detailsBox">
                <h3>Adonis Cars</h3>

            <p>It's a luxuries cars rental agency based in Qatar</p>
            <p><a href="http://adoniscars.com" target="_blank">www.adoniscars.com</a>
            </p>
            <p><strong>Skills:</strong> Web Design</p>
            <p><strong>Date:</strong> 2012</p>
            <p class="share icons"><strong>Share This Project On:</strong>
                <br>    <a href="#" class="facebook" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href), 'facebook-share-dialog', 'width=626,height=436'); return false;" class="facebook"><span>Facebook</span></a>        <a href="#" class="twitter" onclick="return popitup('https://twitter.com/share')"><span>Twitter</span></a>

                <!--Twitter Popup Script-->
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function popitup(url) {
                        newwindow = window.open(url, 'name', 'height=440,width=700');
                        if (window.focus) {
                            newwindow.focus();
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                </script>
            </p>
            <div>   <a href="../portfolio.html">Go Back</a>
    <a class="scrollup">Scroll Up</a>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.imagesGrid, .detailsBox {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.imagesGrid {
    width: 65%;
}
.imagesGrid img {
    border: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
}
.imagesGrid img:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.imagesGrid p {
    border-top: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
    padding-top: 8px;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
.imagesGrid p:first-of-type {
    border-top: none;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.detailsBox {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 347px;
    margin-top: 28px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
.detailsBox p {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
.detailsBox p:first-of-type {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #EAEAEA;
    margin: 0;
}
.detailsBox p:last-of-type {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #EAEAEA;
    margin: 0;
}
.detailsBox a:hover {
    color: #5575A6;
}
.detailsBox div {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    padding: 15px 0;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}
.detailsBox div a {
    background-color: #EAEAEA;
    padding: 10px 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}
.detailsBox div a:hover, .detailsBox div a:active {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #5575A6;
}
.share.icons {
    cursor: default;
}
.share.icons a {
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
.share strong {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.share br {
    display: none;
}
.scrollup {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [**StickyFloat**](http://dropthebit.com/demos/stickyfloat/stickyfloat.html)

It uses JS to achieve what you want. The problem you have is that you're trying to use CSS to conditionally do something, when really that's not what CSS is for

**CSS "Float" VS Javascript**

If you want the floated div to remain at a certain position all the time, that's okay. But CSS cannot differentiate between elements on the page. Here's the [official spec](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp):

```
fixed   The element is positioned relative to the browser window
```

The problem is fixed is related to the browser window only, not other elements. JS, on the other hand, uses the DOM to create an array of elements on the page, which you can create conditions for. It'd highly recommend looking at StickyFloat, or the other "sticky" JS plugins :)

Comment: Thank you, I cant seem to be able to get it working tho :/ can't really find an instruction guide or something. Please advice

Comment: If you post your implementation code, or a JSFiddle, we can help better! Here is the official documentation: https://github.com/yairEO/stickyfloat & you can see a demo at http://firststop.herokuapp.com (add an item to your cart, go to the cart page & see the right-hand-side column do exactly as you want)

Comment: I can't really make a JSFiddle, as most of the content in that page generated using PHP from a database apart from the girds...

However, here is what I have done, I have added the JS file to my assets folder, and then linked to it from the page as follows: `<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/sestickyfloat.js"></script>` and nothing happens. as you can see here: http://www.loaidesign.co.uk/php/projects.php?project=Test_Project

Comment: no mate... I also found this, http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/#reference I find it much simpler but still can't find out how to implant

Comment: Sorry about the late reply - was talking to someone! You've got a number of problems:

1. Your element is "fixed" - the JS does this if I remember correctly
2. You need to have two columns, the right one will act as the container for your element. Currently, you don't have any columns

Comment: I'll try and make a JSfiddle if you like?

Comment: I fixed it! I fixed it!! hahah :D check and tell me if it works: http://www.loaidesign.co.uk/php/projects.php?project=Test_Project It suppose to start scrolling when the header reaches it and stop scrolling when it reaches the footer. Then try to re-size the screen to a phone size, it stop from working and it is positioned relative under the images... is it working?