# how can I make a div stick to the top of the screen once it's been scrolled to and unstick once it hits the footer?

Tags: jquery, css, sticky

I found [this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/HQS8s/) and need to modify it so that when it hits the footer it unsticks. 
I know there is no scroll_bottom, so I was thinking of trying to create a variable for the footer, like below. I will keep plugging away, however, was hoping maybe someone could help out.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Cache selectors for faster performance.
var $window = $(window),
    $mainMenuBar = $('#mainMenuBar'),
    $mainMenuBarAnchor = $('#mainMenuBarAnchor');

// Run this on scroll events.
$window.scroll(function() {
    var window_top = $window.scrollTop();
    var window_bottom = $window.height() - this.scrollTop() - this.height(); 
    var div_top = $mainMenuBarAnchor.offset().top;
    if (window_top > div_top) {
        // Make the div sticky.
        $mainMenuBar.addClass('stick');
        $mainMenuBarAnchor.height($mainMenuBar.height());
    }
    else if (window_bottom > div_top) {
     $mainMenuBar.removeClass('stick');
        $mainMenuBarAnchor.height(0);
    }
    else {
        // Unstick the div.
        $mainMenuBar.removeClass('stick');
        $mainMenuBarAnchor.height(0);
    }
});
```

});

I also found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819842/make-div-stick-to-the-top-of-the-screen-and-stop-before-hitting-the-footer), but can not get it working with jquery 1.7.

Comment: It currently doesn't work. Trying to unstick when it hits the footer.

Comment: It says in the title it should unstick when hitting the footer, no?

Comment: Sorry. I need to have the "sticky panel" div unstick if it hits the footer. Here is my work in progress. http://jsfiddle.net/hansoloshotfirst/T4D52/1/

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/HQS8s/260/ ?

Comment: Ah. Yes. Thanks, this works. However, it is doing a weird flicker on my local dev site. It looks like something to do with the #mainMenuBarAnchor height dynamically getting set. Maybe there is a way to run this without using the #mainMenuBarAnchor? Either way, your fix works, it might just be something with my local site. How do you select your answer as correct solution?

Comment: I posted the code as an answer now :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the job:

**HTML**

You said you wanted a solution without using `#mainMenuBarAnchor`, so delete:

```
<div id="mainMenuBarAnchor"></div>
```

from your HTML code.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Cache selectors for faster performance.
    var $window = $(window),
        $mainMenuBar = $('#mainMenuBar'),
        $menuBarOffset = $mainMenuBar.offset().top,
        window_top = 0,
        footer_offset = $("#footer").offset().top,
        content = $("#content"),
        panel_height = $mainMenuBar.outerHeight()+'px';


    // Run this on scroll events.
    $window.scroll(function() {
        window_top = $window.scrollTop();

        if (window_top >= $menuBarOffset) {
            if (window_top >= footer_offset) {
                // Unstick the div.
                $mainMenuBar.removeClass('stick');
                content.css('margin-top', 0);
            } else {
                // Make the div sticky.
                $mainMenuBar.addClass('stick');
                content.css('margin-top', panel_height);
            }
        }
        else {
            // Unstick the div.
            $mainMenuBar.removeClass('stick');
            content.css('margin-top', 0);
        }
    });
});
```

The code is a little longer now than before, but that's mainly because I added a few variables in the beginning so that you don't have to calculate some stuff on every scroll (like footer offset, the menu bar offset..).

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HQS8s/261/)**