# Position:fixed, then position:absolute after a certain point on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fixed, absolute

How do you make a div tag 
position:fixed, and then absolute, after a certain point on the page?

Here's what I have so far:

```
<div style="position:fixed; top: 26.45%; right: 10%;"></div>
```

Comment: $('#yourid').css({'position':'absolute'});

Comment: You should be able to modify the code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2153775/681807) to serve your purpose. If you are still have problems after then edit the question to show us where specifically you are having trouble