# How to know when the top of window has reached a particular top of a container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I am trying to achieve an effect similar to what [this](http://jsbin.com/ijexe) page shows:  When the top of the window reaches the top of a particular container, I want it to get sticked in the top of the window.

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216114/how-can-i-make-a-div-stick-to-the-top-of-the-screen-once-its-been-scrolled-to) question in SO which deals with this behaviour. But I am not looking the container to get stick when the user reaches a particular px, but when the user reaches the start of a container. I want it this way because the size between the top of the page and the top of the container can vary.

My questions are:

-> How can I know when I have reached the top of a particular container. 
-> If that container has the position: relative, because it has several elements inside which are relatively positioned, and therefore I can't use fixed, what would I do? 
-> How can I reset the container once I scroll up and I reach the same point where it was positioned?

Thanks

Comment: You can use fixed. "[an] absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to _nearest positioned ancestor_." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position ; http://jsfiddle.net/honnza/3nD8t/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
 $(window).scroll(function(e){
 $el = $('.class_of_fixedElement or #id_of_fixedelement');
 if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200 && $el.css('position') != 'fixed'){
 $('.fixedElement').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0px'});
 }
 });
```

replace 200 with whatever pixels you want.as soon as scrolltop reaches there,your element get fixed to top.

Comment: But how do I know where the top of my container is in the loading of the page? I don't know it because the distance between the top and the top of the page can vary.

Comment: @HommerSmith try `.offset().top`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am wondering two things though, and I have edited my question. Once I scroll up, I would need to put the container back again where it was. How could I do this?

Comment: @HommerSmith:you need to write else part where you change its position to relative and top to original value.