# How to hide banner image but fix navigation to top when scrolling?

Tags: html, css

Im trying to get the navigation bar to remain fixed to the top of the browser when the user scrolls down. However I have an image above the navigation and I'd like it to scroll up as well so only the navigation bar remains when scrolling.

The main reason for this is that when the window size is reduced, the logo ends up covering a large portion of the screen and the content becomes very hard to see.

This is what I am trying to accomplish: http://corp.ign.com/

Here's a JSfiddle of what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/cZKeG/

HTML:

```
<div id="topWrapper">
    <a href="index.html">
        <header id="top_header">
            <h1>MacroPlay Games</h1>
        </header>
    </a>
    <nav id="topnav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="video.html">Trailers</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>   
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#topWrapper {
    /*border:1px solid #00ffff;*/
    background-color:#0d0d0d;
    text-align:center;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:9999;
    width:100%;
    max-width: 850px;
    margin: 0 auto; left:0px; right:0px;
    float:clear;
    background-image: url('bg5.jpg');    
}
```

Comment: this has already been asked ... check this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216114/how-can-i-make-a-div-stick-to-the-top-of-the-screen-once-its-been-scrolled-to

Comment: Oh I didn't see this. Perfect, I'll look through it and try to figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: @henser, could you take a look, im having a lot of trouble figuring this out: http://jsfiddle.net/Csf9S/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick look at the code you offer suggests you you are making the whole
topWrapper fixed when you only want the topnav to be fixed

Try this

```
#topnav {
/*border:1px solid #00ffff;*/
background-color:#0d0d0d;
text-align:center;
position:fixed;
z-index:9999;
width:100%;
max-width: 850px;
margin: 0 auto; left:0px; right:0px;
float:clear;
background-image: url('bg5.jpg');
```

}