# sharepoint webpart following scroll in webrowser.....? jquery? or what?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

i have a webpart that i would make that the webpart follows the windows on the right site, so if i scroll down on the page the webpart are following the the screen and scroll??.. I want this because when a user in my first webpart updates something i want him to se in the other webpart what he has updated, so he dont need to scroll to the top of the page to se the webpart that he have updated?

```
window.onscroll = function (oEvent) { or what should i use?
```

should i make put all my code in a `<div>` and call the div or something?
Any suggestions? on best solution?

Comment: Can't CSS (i.e. `position:static`) be used for this? Anyway, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2153775/2246674 as well - it's pretty neat and leads to a good point: *use code (i.e. a plugin) someone else has written, tested and bug-fixed*.

Comment: ehm i solved it using Position:fixed; but then i cannot view the hole webpart text that i have only half why? my page are large,