# How to scroll down a page and once you hit the end of the sidebar, have it stick to the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to reproduce this sidebar:

http://www.fastcodesign.com/3020546/innovation-by-design/would-steve-jobs-have-become-steve-jobs-using-a-computer-designed-by-st

It seems to be that your just scrolling down the page, but once you get to the bottom of the sidebar (and as long as there is still more content to display in the main container,) the sidebar sticks to the bottom of the webpage, but when you scroll back up, the side bar scrolls back up..

How can you reproduce this?

Cheers!

Comment: I Know, but what you have tried? show some code or fiddle

Comment: I have been primarily messing around with Bootstrap because it has a good one, but the version of bootstrap we have on our server isn't up to date so we cant use that.. Right now I have nothing else and I was looking here for some good input on where to start

Comment: Javascript. You could look into jQuery Waypoints sticky function if you like ( http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/ ) which will help you fix items on the page at specific points when scrolling. But go and try to code the thing, this is not really a question for SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of my answer is borrowed from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216114/how-can-i-make-a-div-stick-to-the-top-of-the-screen-once-its-been-scrolled-to).

Here is a basic body/sidebar layout with a sidebarAnchor we will use in our JavaScript/jQuery.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="body">
  <!-- Body content -->
  </div>
  <div id="sidebarAnchor"></div>
  <div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
  <!-- Sidebar Content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS. Most important here is the .sticky class we will add with jQuery. The rest is just there for the demo layout.

```
div.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

div.body {
    width: 45%;
    float: left;
}

div.sidebar {
    width: 45%;
    float: right;
}

.stick {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

And the jQuery/JS. See comments for explanation.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Cache selectors for faster performance.
    var $window = $(window),
        $sidebar = $('#sidebar'),
        $sidebarAnchor = $('#sidebarAnchor');

    // Run this on scroll events.
    $window.scroll(function() {
        var window_top = $window.scrollTop();
        var div_top = $sidebarAnchor.offset().top;
        if (window_top > div_top) {
         // Make the div sticky.
         $sidebar.addClass('stick');
         $sidebarAnchor.height($sidebar.height());
        }
        else {
            // Unstick the div.
            $sidebar.removeClass('stick');
            $sidebarAnchor.height(0);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I incorporated this into my site, and now whenever the user scrolls passed the certain point, the bottom element takes up 100%width of the hole screen. Here is what is happening: http://jsbin.com/EJaveL/1/edit

Comment: You need the anchor to be an empty div that sits right above the div you want to stick. I've fixed it in this [demo](http://example.com). Only weird thing I'm seeing is that the menu duplicated on scroll.

Comment: When I click on the link it just takes me to a page that says "Example Page" @Darion Welch

Comment: Just a note, this solution is similar, not the same, to what OP asked because in his example sidebar would scroll back up as soon as body starts scrolling up and then will become sticky again once it reaches the top while body would continue scrolling. In your solution sidebar waits to reach initial position again before it starts scrolling. Nevertheless, very nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight` is greater than or equal to the sidebar height:

http://jsbin.com/AjagUzi/1/edit?html,css,js,output