# Footer transforms into a Sticky header

Tags: header, footer, sticky-footer

does anyone have the ideea of how to make it?
After scrolling down, the footer will become a sticky header.

like here http://www.oppomobile.in/index.php?open=n1

Thank you.

Comment: Does this do the trick? - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1216130/1693085  or  http://jsfiddle.net/livibetter/HV9HM/

Comment: Now I have to figure how to position it on the desired place on the page.

Comment: I managed to position it in the middle of a text, not by for example "top: 100px;".But after the first scroll, altough it isn't visible yet is sticks to the top of the page.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking....

Comment: I managed :D.Sorry for the confusing question.