# Keep menu on top when "fixed" in css

Tags: javascript, css, menu, fixed

which is positioned 113px from the top, to be on top when users are scrolling the page.

I know there is a similar question, but I am not sure where to put the js code. (Yes I am a newbie)

Old question:
[How to "fixed" menu only when it get to the top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475105/how-to-fixed-menu-only-when-it-get-to-the-top)

Let me know if you want to see an example.

Best regards

Carsten

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post some of your code, it is much easier to be helped if you provide the code you tried

Comment: add jsfiddle or code so that other can help you.

Comment: Well actually, I just need a sticky menu. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example on how to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/andunai/9x74vkvw/

I've also wrapped `.menu` into a `.menu-placeholder` div to reserve place for menu prevent page from "jumping" when it changes state.

You'll need 2 CSS definitions for your menu: `.static` and `.fixed`. Here's the example CSS:

```
.menu {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px 10%;
    display: block;
}

.menu.floating {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 10%;
    width: 10%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JS for this just use:

```
#idOftheDiv 
{
    position:fixed;
    top:113px;
}
```

in your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can put you code in page head like:-

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready({
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    // instead of 113 use the scrollTop when the element touches the top of the window
    if($(window).scrollTop()>=113){
        $(element).css('position', 'fixed');
    }
    else $(element).css('position', 'relative');
});
});
</head>
<body>
// your stuff goes there.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In Magento, where exactly would I put this code? In the template phtml? Why exactly would the code call my menu - if it is only based on one parameter - the 113 px from the top?