# Bootstrap right column overlaps the left column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to have two columns in a navigation bar in bootstrap. But when I do, and I try resizing, the right column overlaps the left. I can't understand why. I see the problem arising from viewport size 769px and persists upto 992px.

**HTML**

```css
.site-wrapper {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     min-height: 100%;
     -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
     box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
     border-top: 5px solid #5A332B;
     background-color: #ccbb99 !important;
    overflow-y: auto;
 }
.navbar {
    border-radius: 0;
    border: none;
    background-color: #683F36;
}
.navbar-brand {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    font-family: chalkitup, "sans-serif";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="site-wrapper">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #8c8c8c;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9" style="background-color: #1b6d85;">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand"><span class="icon ion-arrow-left-c"></span> Back</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color: #3c763d;">
          Scoreboard
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

```
<div class="site-wrapper">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #8c8c8c;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12" style="background-color: #1b6d85;">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand"><span class="icon ion-arrow-left-c"></span> Back</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12" style="background-color: #3c763d;">
          Scoreboard
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have added working example here

```css
.site-wrapper {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     min-height: 100%;
     -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
     box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
     border-top: 5px solid #5A332B;
     background-color: #ccbb99 !important;
    overflow-y: auto;
 }
.navbar {
    border-radius: 0;
    border: none;
    background-color: #683F36;
}
.navbar-brand {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    font-family: chalkitup, "sans-serif";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="site-wrapper">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #8c8c8c;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12" style="background-color: #1b6d85;">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand"><span class="icon ion-arrow-left-c"></span> Back</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12" style="background-color: #3c763d;">
          Scoreboard
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Yep that worked too. On a sidenote, can we affix the second column? (I will accept the answer as soon as I am allowed to.)

Comment: glad to help you :) I don't understand your question means where you want to affix?

Comment: I meant on scroll, I want to fix the second column to the top of screen.

Comment: If you want like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2153775/1306170 the you can do on you code also

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I eventually found the answer to my own question. I had to add the `clearfix` class to the first column in the row. Although it fixed my issue, still would like to know if there are any other views.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="site-wrapper">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #8c8c8c;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9" style="background-color: #1b6d85;">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand"><span class="icon ion-arrow-left-c"></span> Back</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3" style="background-color: #3c763d;">
          Scoreboard
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  You missed to use col-sm-... for small devices
```