# Hide header and stick the div below it to top on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to hide the header and stick the div to top(which is just below the header) when a user starts scrolling down a page.

1. It should remain at the top till a user has reached 350px from top.
2. When user scrolls upwards only the header should be shown and not the div below it.

I have tried with `css`( sticky and fixed position) but it is not giving the desired result.

Here's my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rahulxdd/uy11f99k/6/)

Here's the jquery(I am not good at it) that I tried(with the help of someone) but this is only 25% of what I am trying to achieve.

```
$(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(e) {
    if($(this).scrollTop()>300){
      $('.header').fadeOut(); // Fading in the button on scroll after 300px
    }
    else{
      $('.header').fadeIn(); // Fading out the button on scroll if less than 300px
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: For that you will require jquery. Where is your js code??

Comment: I have added it in the fiddle at the end.

Comment: Nope. there is no js.

Comment: Note my answer below, think it is what you are looking for

Comment: Added the JS that I tried but it is useless because I want the header to hide immidiately after a user scrolls and he div below header to remain sticky until scroll reaches 350px from top.

Answer (score 0):

Cant do this purly with css. Check jquerys [Scroll event](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/), possible soloution

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){ 
  var $el = $('.fixedElement'); 
  var isPositionFixed = ($el.css('position') == 'fixed');
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200 && !isPositionFixed){ 
    $('.fixedElement').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0px'}); 
  }
  if ($(this).scrollTop() < 200 && isPositionFixed)
  {
    $('.fixedElement').css({'position': 'static', 'top': '0px'}); 
  } 
});
```

Added a link in the comments for full soloution.

Comment: No it doesn't solve my purpose and it could also have been done with css alone(position:sticky )

Comment: From what you are trying to do psotion:sticky would not cover all aspects.
Position:sticky only positions a certain element but the logic you are describing has to be triggered with an event, hence why i recommend the scroll event. I would recommed you try it.

Comment: Soloution can alos be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216114/how-can-i-make-a-div-stick-to-the-top-of-the-screen-once-its-been-scrolled-to

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set your header and .newswrap to `position: fixed`. Then this will work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() < 350) {
            $("header").show();
            $(".newswrap").hide();
        } else {
            $("header").hide();
            $(".newswrap").show();
        }
    });
});
```