# How to make a very long div's content always visible?

Tags: html, css

I have some very long divs which every div have only a line of text. So, when user scroll, its content will be invisible. So I want to make the content of these divs always visible.

Could anyone please give me some suggestion about that?

Example:

```css
span {
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 2000px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: table-cell;
}

.red {
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.3);
}

.green {
  background: rgba(0,255,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<div>
<span class="red">
aaaaa
</span>
</div>
<div>
<span class="green">
bbbbb
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "So I want to make the content of these divs always visible"?

Comment: Keep that line of text visible when the user is viewing that div. @mayankbisht

Comment: You may use sticky div inside long divs. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216114/how-can-i-make-a-div-stick-to-the-top-of-the-screen-once-its-been-scrolled-to

Comment: @AliSheikhpour thanks, that solved my problem.

Comment: You may need a little modification to stop sticky at an exact height e.g. 2000