# How to edit this code? Google Map - it should be sticky not floating

Tags: html, google-maps

I have prepared this piece of code. I would like to change two things:
1) width:100% -> doesn't work
2) It should be sticky not floating on my website.
How to change this?

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;width: 1800px;position: relative;"><iframe src="https://maps.google.com/maps?height=300&amp;hl=en&amp;q=United%20Kingdom+(Map)&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=&amp;z=5&amp;iwloc=B&amp;output=embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe></div>
```

I have added to my style.css:

```
iframe {
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
}
```

But If I am changing `<div style="overflow:hidden;width: 1800px;` 
to `<div style="overflow:hidden;width: 100%;`
My map is gone.

Comment: `width` should be applied for both `div` and `iframe`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a div stick to the top of the screen once it's been scrolled to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216114/how-can-i-make-a-div-stick-to-the-top-of-the-screen-once-its-been-scrolled-to)

Comment: I have added to my style.css:

iframe {
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
}

Comment: What do you mean by sticky and floating? Can you show us some more of your html?
You call your map with the parameters `width=800&amp;height=300`. Remove `width=800&amp;` to have it at 100% width

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't use `width: 1800px` as it will produce horizontal scrollbars more often than not. Use `width: 100%` instead.

I added `width: 100%; height: 300px` to both the `div` and the `iframe`. Still not entirely  sure what you mean by "sticky not floating". Just in case, I added `position: sticky` to the `div`, so the map stays on top of the viewport at all times.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.map__container,
.map__iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.map__container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="map__container">
  <iframe class="map__iframe" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?height=300&amp;hl=en&amp;q=United%20Kingdom+(Map)&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=&amp;z=5&amp;iwloc=B&amp;output=embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
</div>
This is content<br> This is content<br> This is content<br> This is content<br> This is content<br> This is content<br> This is content<br> This is content<br> This is content<br> This is content<br> This is content<br> This is content<br> This is content<br>This
is content<br> This is content<br> This is content<br> This is content<br> This is content<br> This is content<br> This is content<br> This is content<br> This is content<br> This is content<br> This is content<br> This is content<br> This is content<br>This
is content<br> This is content<br> This is content<br> This is content<br> This is content<br> This is content<br> This is content<br> This is content<br> This is content<br> This is content<br> This is content<br>
```