# Div stick to the top but keep the same width

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, css-position

I have tried to follow some of the answers here ([How can I make a div stick to the top of the screen once it's been scrolled to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216114/how-can-i-make-a-div-stick-to-the-top-of-the-screen-once-its-been-scrolled-to)), but all of them resize my divs out of the page when scrolled. This one seems to work the best but it has a flicker and kind of wants to return to the top if only a little scroll is present. I am not sure what to do from here so an expert's eye would be appreciated.

```
<div wire:loading.class="opacity-50" class="fixed-scrollbar rounded-lg @unless($complex || $this->hidePagination) rounded-b-none @endunless shadow-lg bg-white max-w-screen overflow-x-scroll border-4 @if($this->activeFilters) border-blue-500 @else border-transparent @endif @if($complex) rounded-b-none border-b-0 @endif">
            <div>
                <div class="fixedElement justify-between items-center mb-1">
                    <div class="h-10 flex items-center">
                        <div class="w-1/6 relative mx-1">
                            <h5>
                                Impressions: {{number_format($total_imp, 2, '.', ',')}}
                            </h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex flex-wrap items-center space-x-1">
                        <x-icons.cog wire:loading class="h-9 w-9 animate-spin text-gray-400" />

                        @if($this->activeFilters)
                        <button wire:click="clearAllFilters" class="flex items-center space-x-2 px-3 border border-red-400 rounded-md bg-white text-red-500 text-xs leading-4 font-medium uppercase tracking-wider hover:bg-red-200 focus:outline-none"><span>{{ __('Reset') }}</span>
                            <x-icons.x-circle class="m-2" />
                        </button>
                        @endif

                        @if($exportable)
                        <div x-data="{ init() {
                            window.livewire.on('startDownload', link => window.open(link, '_blank'))
                        } }" x-init="init">
                            <button wire:click="export" class="flex items-center space-x-2 px-3 border border-green-400 rounded-md bg-white text-green-500 text-xs leading-4 font-medium uppercase tracking-wider hover:bg-green-200 focus:outline-none"><span>{{ __('Export') }}</span>
                                <x-icons.excel class="m-2" /></button>
                        </div>
                        @endif

                        @if($hideable === 'select')
                        @include('datatables::hide-column-multiselect')
                        @endif

                        @foreach ($columnGroups as $name => $group)
                            <button wire:click="toggleGroup('{{ $name }}')"
                                class="px-3 py-2 border border-green-400 rounded-md bg-white text-green-500 text-xs leading-4 font-medium uppercase tracking-wider hover:bg-green-200 focus:outline-none">
                                <span class="flex items-center h-5">{{ isset($this->groupLabels[$name]) ? __($this->groupLabels[$name]) : __('Toggle :group', ['group' => $name]) }}</span>
                            </button>
                        @endforeach
                        <button wire:click="$emit('sec60')"
                                class="px-3 py-2 border border-green-400 rounded-md bg-white text-green-500 text-xs leading-4 font-medium uppercase tracking-wider hover:bg-green-200 focus:outline-none">
                                <span class="flex items-center h-5">60 sec</span>
                        </button>
                        <button wire:click="$emit('sec30')"
                                class="px-3 py-2 border border-green-400 rounded-md bg-white text-green-500 text-xs leading-4 font-medium uppercase tracking-wider hover:bg-green-200 focus:outline-none">
                                <span class="flex items-center h-5">30 sec</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
            
                </div>
                <div class="table align-middle min-w-full">
                    
                    @unless($this->hideHeader)                                       -->
                        <div class="fixedElement1 table-row divide-x divide-gray-200">
                            @foreach($this->columns as $index => $column)
                                @if($hideable === 'inline')
                                    @include('datatables::header-inline-hide', ['column' => $column, 'sort' => $sort])
                                @elseif($column['type'] === 'checkbox')
                                    @unless($column['hidden'])
                                        <div class="table-cell h-6 w-32 py-4 flex justify-center overflow-hidden align-top px-6 border-b border-gray-200 bg-gray-50 text-left text-xs leading-4 font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider focus:outline-none">
                                            <div class="px-3 py-1 rounded @if(count($selected)) bg-orange-400 @else bg-gray-200 @endif text-white text-center">
                                                {{ count($selected) }}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    @endunless
                                @else
                                    @include('datatables::header-no-hide', ['column' => $column, 'sort' => $sort])
                                @endif
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                        <div class="fixedElement2 table-row divide-x divide-blue-200 bg-blue-100">
                            @foreach($this->columns as $index => $column)
                                @if($column['hidden'])
                                    @if($hideable === 'inline')
                                        <div class="table-cell w-5 overflow-hidden align-top bg-blue-100"></div>
                                    @endif
                                @elseif($column['type'] === 'checkbox')
                                    <div class="overflow-hidden align-top bg-blue-100 px-6 py-5 border-b border-gray-200 text-left text-xs leading-4 font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider flex h-full flex-col items-center space-y-2 focus:outline-none">
                                        <div>SELECT ALL</div>
                                        <div>
                                            <input type="checkbox" wire:click="toggleSelectAll" @if(count($selected) === $this->results->total()) checked @endif class="form-checkbox mt-1 h-4 w-4 text-blue-600 transition duration-150 ease-in-out" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                @elseif($column['type'] === 'label')
                                    <div class="table-cell overflow-hidden align-top">
                                        {{ $column['label'] ?? '' }}
                                    </div>
                                @else
                                    <div class="table-cell overflow-hidden align-top">
                                        @isset($column['filterable'])
                                            @if( is_iterable($column['filterable']) )
                                                <div wire:key="{{ $index }}">
                                                    @include('datatables::filters.select', ['index' => $index, 'name' => $column['label'], 'options' => $column['filterable']])
                                                </div>
                                @else
                                    <div wire:key="{{ $index }}">
                                            @include('datatables::filters.' . ($column['filterView'] ?? $column['type']), ['index' => $index, 'name' => $column['label']])
                                    </div>
                                @endif
                            @endisset
                        </div>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            </div>
```

```
.fixedElement {
    position absolute;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    margin-bottom: .25rem!important;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position:fixed;
    align-self: flex-start;
    width:100%;
    z-index:100;
}
.fixedElement1 {
    position absolute;
    display: table-row;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position:fixed;
    align-self: flex-start;
  height: auto;
    width:100%;
    z-index:100;
}
.fixedElement2 {
    position absolute;
    display: table-row;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position:fixed;
    align-self: flex-start;
  height: auto;
    width:100%;
    z-index:100;
}
```

```
  $(window).scroll(function(e){ 
        var $el = $('.fixedElement'); 
        var isPositionFixed = ($el.css('position') == 'fixed');
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200 && !isPositionFixed){ 
            $el.css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '5px', 'background-color': '#fff'}); 
        }
        if ($(this).scrollTop() < 200 && isPositionFixed){
            $el.css({'position': 'static', 'top': '5px'}); 
        } 
        });
        $(window).scroll(function(e){ 
        var $el = $('.fixedElement1'); 
        var isPositionFixed = ($el.css('position') == 'fixed');
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 240 && !isPositionFixed){ 
            $el.css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '45px', 'background-color': '#fff'}); 
        }
        if ($(this).scrollTop() < 240 && isPositionFixed){
            $el.css({'position': 'static', 'top': '45px'}); 
        } 

        });
        $(window).scroll(function(e){ 
        var $el = $('.fixedElement2'); 
        var isPositionFixed = ($el.css('position') == 'fixed');
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300 && !isPositionFixed){ 
            $el.css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '100px'}); 
        }
        if ($(this).scrollTop() < 300 && isPositionFixed){
            $el.css({'position': 'static', 'top': '100px'}); 
        } 
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Is [`position: sticky`](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/) not an option in your case?

Comment: For some reason sticky doesn't do anything.